# Unable to select all users when using twitter API in script

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a bot for Twitter using their API. What it does, is take all the robots I made by "mysql select" and then write down a status for each one.

For some reason it doesn't work when I am trying to select all the robots, it only works if I am changing the following

```
SELECT * FROM tweeterusers
```

to this

```
SELECT * FROM tweeterusers WHERE rid='9'
```

or any other rid (where rid is the robot id I have in the database)

Can you please show me where I am going wrong?

This is the full code

```
<?
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tweeterusers") or die(mysql_error());
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $rid=$info['rid'];
            $ConsumerKey=$info['ConsumerKey'];
            $ConsumerSecret=$info['ConsumerSecret'];
            $AccessToken=$info['AccessToken'];
            $AccessTokenSecret=$info['AccessTokenSecret'];
            $Keyword=$info['Keyword'];
            $TheTweet=$info['TheTweet'];
            $Proxy=$info['Proxy'];

            //echo $rid."<br />";
            //echo $Keyword."<br /><br />";


            define('CONSUMER_KEY', $ConsumerKey);
            define('CONSUMER_SECRET', $ConsumerSecret);
            define('ACCESS_TOKEN', $AccessToken);
            define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', $AccessTokenSecret);

            $twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
            $twitter->host = "http://search.twitter.com/";
            //$search = $twitter->get('search', array('q' => $Keyword, 'rpp' => 1));


            //proxy body
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.twitter.com/1/");
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,$Proxy);
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, '397592562:d6a6cdca');
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);

            $response = curl_exec ($ch);


            //$twitter->host = $response;
            $twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";

            if(is_int($response)) 
            {
                die("Errors: " . curl_errno($ch) . " : " . curl_error($ch));
            }
            curl_close ($ch);


                $status = "hey all";

                if(strlen($status) > 140) $status = substr($status, 0, 139);
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO tweeterstatus 
                (Status, date, time, Robot) VALUES('$status', '$date', '$time', '$rid')");

                $twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $status));



                echo "
                    <tr style='background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #eae9ff;'>
                    <td align='center'>".$rid."</td>
                    <td align='center'>".$Proxy."</td>
                    <td align='center'>".$Keyword."</td>
                    <td align='center'>".$TheTweet."</td>
                    <td align='center'>".$status."</td>
                </tr>";



            sleep(1);
        }

                echo '</table>';
            ?>
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Answer (score 4):

You can not use `define` more than once.

Just use:

```
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($ConsumerKey, $ConsumerSecret, $AccessToken, $AccessTokenSecret);
```

and get rid of the `define`

Comment: I don't understand. Of course you can call `define` more than once. How does omitting a perfectly valid-looking define block fix the problem? What am I missing???

Comment: Technically you can call define more than once, but it only will set the value on the first call. On the next call it returns false and doesn't overwrite the current value.

Comment: @Mike To clarify what stewe said: The `define`s in the OP are done inside a loop. They will be defined correctly on the first iteration, but subsequent attempts to `define` will fail.